# How to produce a set of random numbers based on another randomly selected range in python

Tags: python, loops, random

I need to write a program that generates a random integer named file_size between 4 and 7, inclusive, then print them, but each random integer must be both between 5 and 19 inclusive and be an odd number. Duplicates are okay.To summarize, if file_size is 6, then 6 odd numbers ranging from 5 to 19 must be printed. I'm using Python 3 by the way. This is what I have so far:

```
import random

file_size = random.randint(4, 7)

print("file_size = ", file_size)

for _ in range(file_size):
   random_num = random.randint(5, 19)
   if random_num % 2 ==1:
       print(random_num)
```

Output is as follows for a sample run:

```
file_size =  5
19
11
15
7
```

This obviously isn't what I'm looking for. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is very close. Just use `randrange` with a step of 2 instead of `randint`. This will not generate any even numbers, so you will get the right number of odd ones. However, you need to increase the upper bound by one because `randint` is inclusive of the upper bound but `randrange` is not, like the builtint `range` function.

```
random_num = random.randrange(5, 20, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're loop runs `file_size` times, but only prints when the randomly generated number is odd, meaning you'll generally get less results than desired.  To get a random odd number you'd need to keep generating random values until you get one that is odd, e.g.:

```
def random_odd(low, high):
  while True:
    ret = random.randint(low, high)
    if ret % 2 == 1:
      return ret
```

You can tweak this however you need, and write unit tests to verify the random generation behavior you expect.  Then, use this helper in your `file_size` code:

```
for _ in range(file_size):
  print(random_odd(5, 19))
```

As horns suggests, [`random.randrange()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) is really the function you want, but in general the helper function pattern is a good one to follow - split up your code's responsibility into parts, so that each part is conceptually simpler and can be verified independently.

Comment: Now, instead of printing the numbers I've written them to a file called "numbers.txt". How would I, in another file, read the contents of numbers.txt and then print each number on its own line and then print the sum?